# Connect-N game in C check for wins functions not working

Tags: c, iteration

I'm trying to write a program to play the game Connect-N, which is basically Connect-4 but the user determines the size of the board (it is not necessarily square) and the number of consecutive pieces to win (which can be greater than the size of the board - if the board is 3x3, the user could specify that you need 4 pieces to win, and my code has to play out the game to a tie since it's impossible to win). I'm checking for 4 cases: horizontal win, vertical win, left diagonal win, and right diagonal win. I wrote out the logical steps to actually check for the wins, and then tried to turn that into code. However, when I run the actual program, it keeps returning that it's a tie game even when a player has won, which can only be reached if all 4 win functions return false. Can anyone spot the error in my code?

Here is my code:
(just for reference, the variable pieces represents either an X or O)

Horizontal win:

```
bool horizontalWin(char **board, const int numRows, const int numCols, const char blankSpace, const int numToWin, const char pieces) {
  int match = 0;

  if (numCols < numToWin) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
      for (int col = 0; col <= numCols - numToWin; ++col) {
        for (int k = 0; k < numToWin; ++k) {
          if (board[row][col + k] != pieces) {
            match = 0;
          }
          else {
            ++match;
            if (match == numToWin) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Vertical win:

```
bool verticalWin(char **board, const int numRows, const int numCols, const char blankSpace, const int numToWin, const char pieces) {
  int match = 0;

  if (numRows < numToWin) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col) {
      for (int row = 0; row <= numRows - numToWin; ++row) {
        for(int k = 0; k < numToWin; ++k){
          if (board[row + k][col] != pieces) {
            match = 0;
          }
          else {
            ++match;
            if (match == numToWin) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Left diagonal:

```
bool leftDiagonalWin(char **board, const int numRows, const int numCols, const char blankSpace, const int numToWin, const char pieces) {
  int match = 0;

  if (numCols < numToWin || numRows < numToWin) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    for (int row = 0; row <= numRows - numToWin; ++row) {
      for (int col = 0; col <= numCols - numToWin; ++col) {
        for (int k = 0; k < numToWin; ++k) {
          if(board[k][k] != pieces) {
            match = 0;
          }
          else {
            ++match;
            if (match == numToWin) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Right diagonal:

```
bool rightDiagonalWin(char **board, const int numRows, const int numCols, const char blankSpace, const int numToWin, const char pieces) {
  int match = 0;

  if (numCols < numToWin || numRows < numToWin) {
    return false;
  }
  else {
    for (int row = numRows - 1; row >= numRows - numToWin; --row) {
      for (int col = 0; col <= numCols - numToWin; ++col) {
        for (int k = 0; k < numToWin; ++k) {
          if (board[numRows - 1 - k][col + k] != pieces) {
            match = 0;
          } else {
            ++match;
            if (match == numToWin) {
              return true;
            }
          }
        }
      }

    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

Edit: this is the function I use to create the board:

```
char** createBoard(const int numRows, const int numCols, const char blankSpace) {
  char** board = (char**) malloc(numRows * sizeof(char*));
  for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
    board[row] = (char*) malloc(numCols * sizeof(char));
    for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col) {
      board[row][col] = blankSpace;
    }
  }
  return board;
}
```

Comment: horizontal win is way to complicated. Why do you need 3 loops? Just count how many of the correct piece you have seen on this row - reset to 0 when you see the wrong piece. Only need the rows and cols loops, not an extra 'k' as well - same with vertical but this time you want to go through columns and then rows. Diagonals are trickier, some thought required there.

Comment: And how are these functions called? I'm curious specifically how `board` is declared in the main program.

Comment: @AlexP In main.c I create the board with the line char** board = createBoard(numRows, numCols, blankSpace); and I'll add createBoard to my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your horizontal solution is way too complicated.  The "blankSpace" parameter is not even used or needed. Here's a much, much simplified version:

```
bool horizontalWin(char **board, const int numRows, const int numCols,
                  const int numToWin, const char piece) {

    int match = 0;

    for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
        for (int col = 0; col <= numCols; ++col) {
            match = (board[row][col] == piece) ? (match + 1) : 0;
            if (match == numToWin) {
                break;
            }
        }
     }
    return (match >= numToWin);
}
```

You can pretty much duplicate this same logic for the verticalWin function as well.

Comment: Do you have any insights for the diagonal functions? I'm really struggling with how to iterate down the diagonal without a 3rd for loop.

Comment: One of the easiest optimizations you can make is to use the position of the last piece as a hint on how to scan. For example, if the last piece was dropped at row=4,column=3, then you only need to scan column 3 vertically and row 4 horizontally.  It will make your diagonal logic easier as well.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late:( but this is how I went about it hope it helps

```
    //check win
int checkWin(char *board){
    return (horizontalCheck(board) || verticalCheck(board) || diagonalCheck(board));
}

int checkFour(char *board, int a, int b, int c, int d){
    //board[a] = won;
    //board[b] = won;
    //board[c] = won;
    //board[d] = won;
    return (board[a] == board[b] && board[b] == board[c] && board[c] == board[d] && board[a] != ' ');
}

int horizontalCheck(char *board){
    int row, col, idx;
    const int WIDTH = 1;

    for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS; row++){
       for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS - 3; col++){
          idx = BOARD_COLS * row + col;
          if(checkFour(board, idx, idx + WIDTH, idx + WIDTH * 2, idx + WIDTH * 3)){
             return 1;
          }
       }
    }
    return 0;
}

int verticalCheck(char *board){
    int row, col, idx;
    const int HEIGHT = 7;

    for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS - 3; row++){
       for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS; col++){
          idx = BOARD_COLS * row + col;
          if(checkFour(board, idx, idx + HEIGHT, idx + HEIGHT * 2, idx + HEIGHT * 3)){
              return 1;
          }
       }
    }
    return 0;
}

//diagonal check for win
int diagonalCheck(char *board){
   int row, col, idx, count = 0;
   const int DIAG_RGT = 6, DIAG_LFT = 8;

   for(row = 0; row < BOARD_ROWS - 3; row++){
      for(col = 0; col < BOARD_COLS; col++){
         idx = BOARD_COLS * row + col;
         if(((count <= 3) && (checkFour(board, idx, idx + DIAG_LFT, idx + DIAG_LFT * 2, idx + DIAG_LFT * 3))) ||
             ((count >= 3) && (checkFour(board, idx, idx + DIAG_RGT, idx + DIAG_RGT * 2, idx + DIAG_RGT * 3)))){
            return 1;
         }
         count++;
      }
      count = 0;
   }
   return 0;
}
```